Prove that the series below converges to $\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}$
I'm given the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-n}$ and I want to prove that it converges to $\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}$.
This is the little work I've done:
Consider the sequence of the partial sums $s_n=e^{-1}+2e^{-2}+...+ne^{-n}$. We know that $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$.
Apparently, we can write $ s_n$ as $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2(-2)^{k}}{k!}+...+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(-n)^{k}}{k!}$=$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}+2(-2)^{k}+...+n(-n)^{k}}{k!}$=$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}(1^{k+1}+2^{k+1}+...+n^{k+1})}{k!}$.
I'm not sure how I'm supposed to simplify the latter expression ( especially the large sum in parenthesis) to find where $s_n$ converges to.

Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ne^{-n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{n} (1)e^{-n}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}e^{-n}$.

One approach if you already know about power series:
Note that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $-1< x< 1$.  Differentiate this to get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
Multiply by $x$ to get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n}= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$
and now let $x=\frac{1}{e}$.  You should check that this still lies within the interval of convergence, so all is well.

Amazing! thank you

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-n}&=x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots\text{ (Let $x=e^{-1}$)}\\
&=x+(x^2+x^2)+(x^3+x^3+x^3)+\cdots\\
&=(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)+(x^2+x^3+\cdots)+(x^3+\cdots)+\cdots\\
&=x(1+x+x^2+\cdots)+x^2(1+x+\cdots)+x^3(1+\cdots)+\cdots\\
&=(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)\\
&=x(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^2\\
&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{e^{-1}}{(1-e^{-1})^2}\\
&=\frac{e^{-1}\times e^2}{(1-e^{-1})^2\times e^2}\\
&=\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}\\
\end{align*}$$
Note: since $-1<e^{-1}<1$, the formula for power series works

I took a slightly different approach to those given previously by defining some new series as follows:
Define $t_1=e^{-1}+e^{-2}+...$
And $t_2=e^{-2}+e^{-3}+...$
So in general, $t_n=e^{-n}+e^{-(n+1)}+...$
Each of these is an infinite geometric progression with infinite sums (the sum to infinity exists because the common ratio, $-1< \frac{1}{e} <1$:
$t_1=\frac{1}{e-1},t_2=\frac{e^{-1}}{e-1},...t_n=\frac{e^{-(n-1)}}{e-1},...$
Each of these sums are then consecutive terms in another geometric progression whose sum gives $s_n$ so we can write $s_n=t_1+t_2+...+t_n+...$
Which means $s_n=\frac{1}{e-1}(1+e^{-1}+e^{-2}+...+e^{-(n-1)}+...$
And since this is another infinite geometric series whose common ratio is also $\frac{1}{e}$ the sum to infinity exists.
$s_n=\frac{1}{e-1}(1\div(\frac{e-1}{e}))=\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}$
